# Onclick shows menu links, but it never disappears

Tags: javascript, menu, onclick

I would like to click on "Fruit" and have the list appear. However when I click on "Fruit" now, my list of fruits appear but it never dissappears. When I click on the next link "Vegetables", fruit disappears, but now Vegetables won't dissaper even if I click somewhere else on the screen or move the mouse.

```
$('.menuBar div ul li').click(function() {
    $('.menuBar div').hide();
});

    function showHideMenu( elem ) {
   $('.menuBar div').each( function () {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('sub' + elem) ) {
        $(this).css('height','0px');
        $(this).css('display','inline-block');
        $(this).animate({
         height: '+=200'
        },'slow');
    } else {
        $(this).css('display','none');
    }
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
<div class="menuBar">
   <ul> 
       <li onclick="showHideMenu('Fruit');">
           <span class="fruit"></span>Fruit
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: where are the list of fruits ? in an array or object

Comment: Do you not need to call the showHideMenu function a second time?

Comment: menu should be hidden on click on body event and click target not on menubar

Comment: It seems like the code is correct but I am missing additional code to instruct a "mouseout" event to hide the list of fruit.